# JQuery Flot in JQuery Steps

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am a beginner and I try to use the JQuery Flot in a tab made with JQuery Steps. But no graph appears in the tab yet it exists in HTML(As if he were behind).

I Think the error is in CSS, but I'm not yet good enough.

```css
body {
  background: #36c;
  color: #555;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 16px/1.4 Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
div.content {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}
fieldset legend {
  font-style: italic;
  color: silver;
}
fieldset label {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
input[type=text] {
  font-size: 100%;
  padding: 0.2em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
button {
  color: #666;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.2em 2em;
  font-size: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
button:hover {
  background: #ccc;
}
code {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 0 0.3em;
  color: #396;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #69c;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#graphs {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
#example-basic {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.graph {
  min-height: 12em;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  width: 36em;
  display: block;
}
.graph_title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5em;
  left: 1em;
  color: #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 999;
}
/*
Common 
*/

.wizard,
.tabcontrol {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wizard a,
.tabcontrol a {
  outline: 0;
}
.wizard ul,
.tabcontrol ul {
  list-style: none !important;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wizard ul > li,
.tabcontrol ul > li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Accessibility */

.wizard > .steps .current-info,
.tabcontrol > .steps .current-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}
.wizard > .content > .title,
.tabcontrol > .content > .title {
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}
/*
Wizard
*/

.wizard > .steps {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.wizard.vertical > .steps {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}
.wizard > .steps .number {
  font-size: 1.429em;
}
.wizard > .steps > ul > li {
  width: 25%;
}
.wizard > .steps > ul > li,
.wizard > .actions > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
.wizard.vertical > .steps > ul > li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.wizard > .steps a,
.wizard > .steps a:hover,
.wizard > .steps a:active {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.wizard > .steps .disabled a,
.wizard > .steps .disabled a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .disabled a:active {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
  cursor: default;
}
.wizard > .steps .current a,
.wizard > .steps .current a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .current a:active {
  background: #2184be;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
.wizard > .steps .done a,
.wizard > .steps .done a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .done a:active {
  background: #9dc8e2;
  color: #fff;
}
.wizard > .steps .error a,
.wizard > .steps .error a:hover,
.wizard > .steps .error a:active {
  background: #ff3111;
  color: #fff;
}
.wizard > .content {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0.5em;
  min-height: 35em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.wizard.vertical > .content {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2.5% 0.5em 2.5%;
  width: 65%;
}
.wizard > .content > .body {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 2.5%;
}
.wizard > .content > .body ul {
  list-style: disc !important;
}
.wizard > .content > .body ul > li {
  display: list-item;
}
.wizard > .content > .body > iframe {
  border: 0 none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wizard > .content > .body input {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.wizard > .content > .body input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wizard > .content > .body input.error {
  background: rgb(251, 227, 228);
  border: 1px solid #fbc2c4;
  color: #8a1f11;
}
.wizard > .content > .body label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.wizard > .content > .body label.error {
  color: #8a1f11;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}
.wizard > .actions {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}
.wizard.vertical > .actions {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  width: 95%;
}
.wizard > .actions > ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
.wizard > .actions > ul > li {
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}
.wizard.vertical > .actions > ul > li {
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}
.wizard > .actions a,
.wizard > .actions a:hover,
.wizard > .actions a:active {
  background: #2184be;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.wizard > .actions .disabled a,
.wizard > .actions .disabled a:hover,
.wizard > .actions .disabled a:active {
  background: #eee;
  color: #aaa;
}
.wizard > .loading {} .wizard > .loading .spinner {}
/*
Tabcontrol
*/

.tabcontrol > .steps {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.tabcontrol > .steps > ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 6px 0 0 0;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 2px 0 0;
  padding: 1px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li:hover {
  background: #edecec;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 0;
}
.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li.current {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
  padding: 0 0 1px 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li > a {
  color: #5f5f5f;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0 none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabcontrol > .steps > ul > li.current > a {
  padding: 15px 30px 10px 30px;
}
.tabcontrol > .content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.tabcontrol > .content > .body {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  padding: 2.5%;
}
.tabcontrol > .content > .body ul {
  list-style: disc !important;
}
.tabcontrol > .content > .body ul > li {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Connected device demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jquery.steps.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/normalize.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/jquery.cookie-1.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/jquery.steps.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/main.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/jquery.steps.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="logo.png" style="float:right; height: 50px; border-radius: 3px;">
    <h1>Connected device demo - Websocket push</h1>

    <p>
      This page is one of the series of examples that show how to make devices connected with Mongoose. Here we add a real-time Websocket server push, and update dashboard graph as data arrives.
    </p>

    <h1>Settings section</h1>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#example-basic").steps({
          headerTag: "h3",
          bodyTag: "section",
          transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
          enableFinishButton: false,
          enablePagination: false,
          enableAllSteps: true,
          titleTemplate: "#title#"
        });
      });
    </script>


    <div id="example-basic">
      <h3>CPU usage</h3>
      <section>

      </section>
      <h3>Settings</h3>
      <section>
        <form method="POST" action="/save">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Device settings</legend>
            <label>Setting 1:</label>
            <input type="text" name="setting1" value="<!--#call setting1 -->">
            <label>Setting 2:</label>
            <input type="text" name="setting2" value="<!--#call setting2 -->">
            <h1>Dashboard section</h1>
            <label>CPU usage:</label> <span id="cpu_usage">&nbsp;</span>

            <div id="graphs"></div>
            <div>
              <button type="submit">Save Settings</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am a taker of any advice.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Begin with this `$(document).ready(function(){
//All your JS code
});`

Comment: Do you get any errors such as else than `$ is not defined` (in the code snippet) in the Console?

Comment: @Tinsten I add my function to $(document).ready(function(){ //All your JS code });. And I haven't $ is not defined  in snippet.